# Android Studio cannot resolve classes in aar even though they are in the arr/classes.jar

Tags: android, gradle, artifactory

I am publishing an android library module to my server's artifactory service. When I download the aar file and extract the classes.jar file I can see my packages:

```
drwxrwxr-x 4 yon yon 4096 Jul 28 14:44 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 yon yon 4096 Jul 28 14:44 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yon yon  594 Jul 28 14:18 BuildConfig.class
drwxrwxr-x 2 yon yon 4096 Jul 28 14:44 event
drwxrwxr-x 2 yon yon 4096 Jul 28 14:44 widget
```

including the java files inside the packages:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 yon yon 4096 Jul 28 14:44 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 yon yon 4096 Jul 28 14:44 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 yon yon  425 Jul 28 14:18 QRFinishedEvent.class
```

After configuring the repo settings in my project level build.gradle:

```
 maven {
       url "myserver/artifactory/libs-release-local"
       credentials {
           username = "${artifactory_username}"
           password = "${artifactory_password}"
       }
 }
```

I can resolve the dependency in my app-level build.gradle:

```
compile(group: mygroup, name: mypackage, version: '1.0.0', ext: 'aar')
```

And it downloads successfuly. However in Android Studio I cannot resolve the packages that were present in classes.jar. Only R and BuildConfig seem to be resolvable.

How can this be resolved?

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 and build tools 23.0.1 for both the aar module and the project depending on it.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by bumping the version of my library in both the build.gradle of the library module and the build.gradle of the app depending on it.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and bumping the version helps, though still don't know why. Using Android Studio 2.2.2 and build tools 2.2.2

Comment: Gradle doesn't like it if you don't bump the version when you revise the library.